# Did Thunderbolt Ross dye his hair after The Incredible Hulk and why?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, continuity, captain-america-civil-war, the-incredible-hulk-2008

Thunderbolt Ross was depicted with blonde-white hair and moustache in the movie *The Incredible Hulk*.

But his appearance in this aspect was changed in other MCU films. His moustache became near black, and his hair became partially black.

Why did this happen?

[image: Side by side comparison of Ross in Incredible Hulk and in Civil War]

Comment: Maybe he just *dyed* it? Also, every other facial feature clearly shows he's older than before.

Comment: https://www.justformen.com/ - even Generals can be vain

Comment: @Shreedhar Why didn't he dye completely?

Comment: @aminabzz Because he *loves* that salt & pepper look. Slightly more seriously, in *Hulk*, he's a general; in *Civil War*, he's [Secretary of State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Secretary_of_State), meaning he's a very high-profile figure in American and international politics, meaning appearance matters. If he completely dyed it, it'd probably look super-fake for a guy of his age. But a partial job looks more natural, and less grandpa than his actual appearance. As long as his hair doesn't [turn red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hulk), it's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *The Incredible Hulk*, Ross is a military general; in *Civil War*, he's [Secretary of State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Secretary_of_State).

That means he's a very high-profile figure in American and international politics, and so his appearance matters. A partial dye-job (assuming that's what changed his hair colour) looks reasonably natural, and makes him look less like a doddering grandpa than he otherwise would (while hopefully avoiding the risks associated with [more extensive adaptations of appearance](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/nov/19/rudy-giuliani-dye-my-cousin-vinny-press-conference)).

So: probably just a makeover, nothing to worry about. Save that for [when his hair starts turning red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hulk).